# Expand width of div depending on the content

Tags: html, css

I've gone through so many questions answered on this site and nothing will work. I have a container and I'm trying to allow horizontal scroll on my smaller divs and it will not let me.

CSS

```
#theLoopTasksLabels {
    width:90%;
    height:90px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left:10px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;



}

#categoryTasksLabels {
    height:70px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#categoryTasksLabels  > h6 {
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#B6B6B6;
}


#loopsTasksLabels {
    width: 110%;
    height: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;



}

#loopsTasksLabels > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#circleTaskLabels {
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:4px;
    color:#fbfbfb;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="theLoopTasksLabels">


        <div id="loopsTasksLabels">

                <div id="categoryTasksLabels">

                    <div id="circleTaskLabels" style="background-color:#eaa5a2">Label</div> <br>
                    <h6><span> 4</span> | <span>6</span></h6>

                </div>

                <div id="categoryTasksLabels">

                    <div id="circleTaskLabels" style="background-color:#eaa5a2">Label</div> <br>
                    <h6><span> 4</span> | <span>6</span></h6>

                </div>

                <div id="categoryTasksLabels">

                    <div id="circleTaskLabels" style="background-color:#eaa5a2">Label</div> <br>
                    <h6><span> 4</span> | <span>6</span></h6>

                </div>

        </div>


</div>
```

For reasons unbeknownst to me, it is not working. I tried adding everything other answers have told the question's OPs, but nothing.

I just acts as a horizontal scroll until I've overfilled the div's width with content. The content I'm trying to scroll through is `<div id="categoryTasksLabels">` how ever many the user creates, so there is no set number. I don't know what else to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get the horizontal scroll like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fxnsb78m/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxnsb78m/1/ I updated it with more content and you can see how it goes to the next line

Comment: No, it doesn't go to the next line here :-/ http://i.imgur.com/HsZUice.png?1

Comment: I don't really get your problem.. It looks fine to me..

Comment: Here, more content for you to see what I mean, http://jsfiddle.net/fxnsb78m/2/

Comment: http://imgur.com/JvEvRHf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, you shouldn't be using ID's to style multiple elements, use classes instead.

Apart from this, removing the "float: left" from ".loopsTasksLabels > div "seems to make it work for me.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciated, I'll keep that in mind, too! Have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem =). Remember "float" tries to position an element as close to one of the top corners as possible, so "float: left" will end up positioning elements underneath just to get closer to the top left corner. It doesn't imply horizontality.

Comment: Oh, what the heck, okay, that makes so much sense, thank you :D